# Set InkCanvas.InkPresenter Binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-10, uwp

I have a class called `DataModel` where I am storing all information about my app's state. In there I have a property called `DeviceInput`, typed as `CoreInputDeviceTypes`. That is where I am holding the value for whether or not touch is enabled for my `InkCanvas`. I want to bind my `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes` property to the `DeviceInput` property. I have created a `Binding`:

```
Binding inputBinding = new Binding();
inputBinding.Source = DataModel.DeviceInput;
inputBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
```

The problem is that I can't find any way to set the binding to the `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes` property. If I try to do:

```
MyInkCanvas.SetBinding(InkCanvas.InkPresenter...)
```

`InkPresenter` isn't available. This makes sense because `InkPresenter` is a child, not a Dependency Property. But neither can I do

```
MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.SetBinding(...)
```

I'm guessing that this is because `InkPresenter` comes from `Windows.UI.Inking` rather than `Windows.UI.Xaml`. But is there any way to set a binding on this property?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can workaround this using a custom dependency property. Something like the following:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputDTsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InputDTs", typeof(Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(InputDTsPropertyChanged))); 

    public Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes InputDTs
    {
        //get;
        //set;
    }

    private static void InputDTsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes here
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Binding inputBinding = new Binding();
        inputBinding.Source = DataModel.DeviceInput;
        inputBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        this.SetBinding(InputDTsProperty, inputBinding);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately though this would break my model for keeping all the data in one place and merely having the UI reflect it. Prefer another way, if possible.